# Applying a style with gdal2tiles.py

Tags: leaflet, gis, raster, gdal

I'm in need of a free command-line tiling program. I wish to take a raster dataset and create a standard 'slippy' directory of PNG files for inclusion in a Leaflet webmap. I'm currently trying out gdal2tile.py, which seems to work fine with one issue: I cannot figure out how to apply a style to it! I would like to be able to add colors and stretches to the raster so that the tiles aren't just greyscale.

Is this possible in gdal2tiles.py (or some other GDAL utility)? I'm using Ubuntu, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible in gdal2tiles.py?

No.

`gdal2tiles` does one job only: slice a raster dataset into tiles, nothing more.

> ...or in some other GDAL utility?

Yes.

If you want to convert grayscale to something like color ramps or gradients, [`gdaldem`](https://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html) seems like a good fit. With that, you'll be able to create a new raster dataset with either 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) colour channels, and *then* you can use `gdal2tiles` on that.

See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130199/changing-color-of-raster-images-based-on-their-data-values-gdal